# Getting the backup directory of an SQL Server 2014 via Powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

On an SQL Server 2012 machine I use the following Powershell script to get the configured backup directory:

```
$srv = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server("localhost")
$BackupDirectory = $srv.Settings.BackupDirectory
Write-Host $BackupDirectory
```

When running the same script on a machine with SQL Server 2014 the result is empty. Via SQL Management Studio however I can see that the directory is configured correctly. The script doesn't cause any errors.

What might I be missing here?

Comment: The above script works for me on a SQL Server 2014 instance w/ Service Pack 2 installed. Is your local 2014 instance standard instance or a named instance?

Comment: It's the standard instance.

Answer (score 1):

One reason the value is blank is **when you don't have permissions** to access the instance you are connecting to. The value for `$BackupHistory` is then empty.

Ensure you are connecting to the correct instance:

```
$srv = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server("<host_name>\<instance_name>")
```

or for the default instance:

```
$srv = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server("<host_name>")
```

E.g. for an instance named `2014INSTANCE` on a local SQL Server installation with multiple instances:

```
$srv = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server("localhost\2014INSTANCE")
```

The rest of the statement should then work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the script didn't return anything was that my Windows user was not allowed to login to the SQL server instance. I didn't recognize this as other applications use their dedicated logins.

Adter having added the Windows user the script works fine.